# Probability Inequalities (Markov and Chebychev)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables taking values in $\mathbb N$. Let $E[X]=5,E[Y]=9, Var(Y) = \frac{1}{4}$. Show:

$P( \{ X \leq 10 \} \cap \{Y=9 \} ) \geq \frac{1}{4}$

I have shown that $P(\{ X \leq 10 \} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ using Markov's inequality. Now I am stuck.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independant?

Comment: @Youem No they are not

Comment: Since $Y \in \mathbb{N}$, note that $\text{Var}(Y) = \mathbb{E}[(Y - 9)^2] \geq 1 \cdot \Pr(Y \neq 9) \implies \Pr(Y \neq 9) \leq 1/4$. The result follows immediately from this result when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I am not sure if one can show this result for all possible joint distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Couldn't I use Chebychev's inequality with a value of $\epsilon$?

Comment: You could use Chebyshev's inequality with $\varepsilon$ close to $1$ (say $0.999$) and you will get a similar result. However, I personally feel that Chebyshev isn't the neatest way to solve this unless the question insists you to use it.

Comment: @sudeep5221 I think I should use Chebyshev. Could you show me how to use it to solve this question please ?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Chebyshev's inequality is equivalent to your result, especially if you use it in the form $\Pr(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ with $\sigma=\frac12$ and $k=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P\left[X \le 10 \cap Y = 9\right] &= P\left[X \le 10\right] - P\left[X\le 10\, \cap\, Y\neq 9\right]\\
&\ge P\left[X \le 10\right] - P\left[Y\neq 9\right]
\end{align}

Use Chebyshev inequality with $\epsilon = 1$ to bound $P\left[Y\neq 9\right]$. Can you finish the proof?